# Backbone.js Parse Method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I am trying to unit test my first backbone.js application using [sinon.js and jasmine.js](http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/25/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-2.html).

In this particular test case, I used the sinon.js fakeServer method to return a dummy response with the following structure.

```
beforeEach( function(){
  this.fixtures = {
    Tasks:{
      valid:{
        "tasks":[
          {
            id: 4,
            name:'Need to complete tests',
            status: 0
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name:'Need to complete tests',
            status: 1
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name:'Need to complete tests',
            status: 2,
          }
        ]
      }
     }
    };
  });
```

So when I actually call the fetch call in the below test case, it returns the 3 models correctly. In the parse method of the collection, I tried to remove the root 'tasks' key and just return the array of objects alone, which was mentioned in the backbone.js documentation. But when I do this, no models are getting added to the collection and the collection.length returns 0.

```
   describe("it should make the correct request", function(){

    beforeEach( function(){
      this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
      this.tasks = new T.Tasks();
      this.server.respondWith('GET','/tasks', this.validResponse( this.fixtures.Tasks.valid) );
    });

    it("should add the models to the tasks collections", function(){
      this.tasks.fetch();
      this.server.respond();
      expect( this.tasks.length ).toEqual( this.fixtures.Tasks.valid.tasks.length );
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      this.server.restore();
    });

  });
```

**Task Collection**

```
  T.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: T.Task,
    url:"/tasks",
    parse: function( resp, xhr ){
      return resp["tasks"];
    }
  });
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're code looks great from here.  Can you post your `Task` Backbone Model?

Comment: @BrentAnderson I found what is the problem. In the Task Model, I have the validate method which was validating the argument 'attrs', by first checking attrs.hasOwnProperty and then the condition. But it failed in the case there were null and undefined. So I added them and now the tests are working fine. Thanks :)

Comment: @felix You should add your solution as an answer and mark it correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with my code was in the validate method of the model and not the parse method of the collection. I was testing for the attributes even when they dont exist. The object that is sent to validate will not have all the attributes every time. For example, in a task model with id,title and status, where status is set as 0 by default, if I create a model like

```
var t = new Task({'title':'task title'});
t.save();
```

here, the validate method will only get {'title':'task title'} as a parameter to the validate method.

So it is important to add those conditions too in the validate method and when I added conditions to check for the presence of the particular attribute and also when it is not null or undefined, my tests started passing.